# Storing a string in char* in C

Tags: c, linked-list

In the code below, I hope you can see that I have a `char*` variable and that I want to read in a string from a file. I then want to pass this string back from the function. I'm rather confused by pointers so I'm not too sure what I'm supposed to do really.

The purpose of this is to then pass the array to another function to be searched for a name.

Unfortunately the program crashes as a result and I've no idea why.

```
char* ObtainName(FILE *fp)
{
    char* temp;
    int i = 0;

    temp = fgetc(fp);
    while(temp != '\n')
    {
        temp = fgetc(fp);
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s", temp);
    return temp;
}
```

Any help would be vastly appreciated.

Comment: Two problems: no storage for `temp` (it's only a pointer, but doesn't have anywhere to point), and you aren't using `i` to index `temp`. It's often best to simply pass in a char array to be filled by the function.

Comment: @ooga: Well, the OP seems to think that `fgetc` returns a `char*`. If that were true then the assignment and read would be fine.

Comment: @EdS. So there is method to the madness!

Comment: `temp = fgetc(fp);` should have generated a warning.  Suggest insuring your warnings are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

`fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char*`.  This `int` is a character from the stream, or `EOF` if you reach the end of the file.

You're implicitly casting the `int` to a `char*`, i.e., interpreting it as an address (turn your warnings on.)  When you call `printf` it reads that address and continues to read a character at a time looking for the null terminator which ends the string, but that address is almost certainly invalid.  This is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken some liberties with what you wanted to accomplish.  Rather that deal with pointers, you can just use a fixed sized array as long as you can set a maximum length.  I've also included several checks so that you don't run off the end of the buffer or the end of the file.  Also important is to make sure that you have a null termination '\0' at the end of the string.

```
#define MAX_LEN 100
char* ObtainName(FILE *fp)
{
    static char temp[MAX_LEN];
    int i = 0;

    while(i < MAX_LEN-1)
    {
        if (feof(fp)) 
        {
            break;
        }
        temp[i] = fgetc(fp);
        if (temp[i] == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    temp[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s", temp);
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, there are several problems here:

1. You're not setting aside any storage for the string contents;
2. You're not storing the string contents correctly;
3. You're attempting to read memory that doesn't belong to you;
4. The way you're attempting to return the string is going to give you heartburn.

**1.  You're not setting aside storage for the string contents**

The line

```
char *temp;
```

declares `temp` as a pointer to `char`; its value will be the *address* of a single character value.  Since it's declared at local scope without the `static` keyword, its initial value will be indeterminate, and that value may not correspond to a valid memory address.

It does not set aside any storage for the string contents read from `fp`; that would have to be done as a separate step, which I'll get to below.

**2.  You're not storing the string contents correctly**

The line

```
temp = fgetc(fp);
```

reads the next character from `fp` and assigns it to `temp`.  First of all, this means you're only storing the last character read from the stream, not the whole string.  Secondly, and more importantly, you're assigning the result of `fgetc()` (which returns a value of type `int`) to an object of type `char *` (which is treated as an address).  You're basically saying "I want to treat the letter 'a' as an address into memory."  This brings us to...

**3.  You're attempting to read memory that doesn't belong to you**

In the line

```
printf("%s", temp);
```

you're attempting to print out the string beginning at the address stored in `temp`.  Since the last thing you wrote to `temp` was most likely a character whose value is < 127, you're telling `printf` to start at a very low and most likely not accessible address, hence the crash.

**4.  The way you're attempting to return the string is guaranteed to give you heartburn**

Since you've defined the function to return a `char *`,  you're going to need to do one of the following:

- Allocate memory dynamically to store the string contents, and then pass the responsibility of freeing that memory on to the function calling this one;
- Declare an array with the `static` keyword so that the array doesn't "go away" after the function exits; however, this approach has serious drawbacks;
- Change the function definition;

**Allocate memory dynamically**

You could use dynamic memory allocation routines to set aside a region of storage for the string contents, like so:

```
char *temp = malloc( MAX_STRING_LENGTH * sizeof *temp );
```

or

```
char *temp = calloc( MAX_STRING_LENGTH, sizeof *temp );
```

and then return `temp` as you've written.

Both `malloc` and `calloc` set aside the number of bytes you specify; `calloc` will initialize all those bytes to 0, which takes a little more time, but can save your bacon, especially when dealing with text.

The problem is that somebody has to deallocate this memory when its no longer needed; since you return the pointer, whoever calls this function now has the responsibility to call `free()` when it's done with that string, something like:

```
void Caller( FILE *fp )
{
  ...
  char *name = ObtainName( fo );
  ...
  free( name );
  ...
}
```

This spreads the responsibility for memory management around the program, increasing the chances that somebody will forget to release that memory, leading to memory leaks.  *Ideally*, you'd like to have the same function that allocates the memory free it.

**Use a static array**

You could declare `temp` as an *array* of `char` and use the `static` keyword:

```
static char temp[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
```

This will set aside `MAX_STRING_SIZE` characters in the array when the program starts up, and it will be preserved between calls to `ObtainName`.  No need to call `free` when you're done.

The problem with *this* approach is that by creating a static buffer, the code is not *re-entrant*; if `ObtainName` called another function which in turn called `ObtainName` again, that new call will clobber whatever was in the buffer before.

Why not just declare `temp` as

```
char temp[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
```

without the `static` keyword?  The problem is that when `ObtainName` exits, the `temp` array ceases to exist (or rather, the memory it was using is available for someone else to use).  That pointer you return is no longer valid, and the contents of the array may be overwritten before you can access it again.

**Change the function definition**

Ideally, you'd like for `ObtainName` to not have to worry about the memory it has to write to.  The best way to achieve that is for the caller to pass target buffer as a parameter, along with the buffer's size:

```
int ObtainName( FILE *fp, char *buffer, size_t bufferSize )
{
  ...
}
```

This way, `ObtainName` writes data into the location that the caller specifies (useful if you want to obtain multiple names for different purposes).  The function will return an integer value, which can be a simple success or failure, or an error code indicating why the function failed, etc.

Note that if you're reading text, you don't have to read character by character; you can use functions like `fgets()` or `fscanf()` to read an entire string at a time.

Use `fscanf` if you want to read whitespace-delimited strings (i.e., if the input file contains `"This is a test"`, `fscanf( fp, "%s", temp);` will only read `"This"`).  If you want to read an entire line (delimited by a newline character), use `fgets()`.

Assuming you want to read an individual string at a time, you'd use something like the following (assumes C99):

```
#define FMT_SIZE 20
...
int ObtainName( FILE *fp, char *buffer, size_t bufsize )
{
  int result = 1;  // assume success
  int scanfResult = 0;

  char fmt[FMT_SIZE];    
  sprintf( fmt, "%%%zus", bufsize - 1 ); 

  scanfResult = fscanf( fp, fmt, buffer );
  if ( scanfResult == EOF )
  {
    // hit end-of-file before reading any text
    result = 0;
  }
  else if ( scanfResult == 0 )
  {
    // did not read anything from input stream
    result = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    result = 1;
  }

  return result;
}
```

So what's this noise

```
char fmt[FMT_SIZE];    
sprintf( fmt, "%%%zus", bufsize - 1 );
```

about?  There is a very nasty security hole in `fscanf()` when you use the `%s` or `%[` conversion specifiers without a maximum length specifier.  The `%s` conversion specifier tells `fscanf` to read characters until it sees a whitespace character; if there are more non-whitespace characters in the stream than the buffer is sized to hold, `fscanf` will store those extra characters past the end of the buffer, clobbering whatever memory is following it.  This is a common malware exploit.  So we want to specify a maximum length for the input; for example, `%20s` says to read no more than 20 characters from the stream and store them to the buffer.

Unfortunately, since the buffer length is passed in as an argument, we can't write something like `%20s`, and `fscanf` doesn't give us a way to specify the length as an argument the way `fprintf` does.  So we have to create a separate format string, which we store in `fmt`.  If the input buffer length is 10, then the format string will be `%10s`.  If the input buffer length is 1000, then the format string will be `%1000s`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code expands on that in your question, and returns the string in allocated storage:

```
char* ObtainName(FILE *fp)
   {
   int temp;
   int i = 1;
   char *string = malloc(i);
   if(NULL == string)
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed\n");
      goto CLEANUP;
      }
   *string = '\0';       

   temp = fgetc(fp);
   while(temp != '\n')
      {
      char *newMem;
      ++i;

      newMem=realloc(string, i);
      if(NULL==newMem)
         {
         fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed.\n");
         goto CLEANUP;
         }
      string=newMem;
      string[i-1] = temp;
      string[i] = '\0';

      temp = fgetc(fp);
      }

CLEANUP:

   printf("%s", string);
   return(string);
   }
```

Take care to 'free()' the string returned by this function, or a memory leak will occur.